# Compare two glob expressions

Tags: python, compare, wildcard, expression, glob

Does anyone know an algorithm to check which of two wild card expression is more general than the other? 
For example I'd like to compare

```
*/foo/foo.bar
```

with

```
*.bar
```

Clearly the first expression is contained in the second. I know that is not possible for regex (at least not if you don't have a looooot of time, as far as I remember this is in complexity class Non elementary), but it could be possible for wild card expression which are far less expressive. I tried to put together a simple python algorithm, but it get's very nasty when it comes to special cases.
Anybody has an idea if there is an algorithm for that problem?

UPDATE:

I do not want to use any brute force algorithm, since this won't work in general, because of performance reasons

Regards,

Gerald

Comment: AFAIK *.bar will only look for files in the immediate dir (atleast in glob.glob).

Comment: The second one does not include the first one, but `*/foo/*.bar` includes the first one, as well as `*/*/*.bar`.

Comment: OK, than let's rephrase it from glob expression to wildcard expression (also containing '?'), to be more general. I'm trying to compare rules with such expressions in it and merge/reorder them together to a single rule set. And the order of the rules in this set is relevant, e.g. the behavior for all *.bar files may be different from the behavior of the file foo.bar in the sepcified directory

Comment: Please edit/update your question with clarifications, rather than leaving them solely in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to find a string somehow that matches the more general glob but not the more specific one. Just being captain obvious...

Probably by replacing `*` character with 0 or more random symbols.

Comment: I think some sort of brute force won't work for performance reasons.